# In python, can I find the file name of the script being executed, instead of __main__?

Tags: python

```
mModule.__name__
```

Will helpfully return the module's name when imported. But when run as a script it will (also helpfully) return

```
 __main__
```

Is there a simple way to get the file name of a module currently being run as a script?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary That's the file of the current module, rather than the currently executing script.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary More precisely, that will give the name of the file the statement appears in. Which is obviously the same thing if that's the actual file being run as script but not necessarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [`sys.argv[0]`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html) is your best bet - it should work from any module, not only the main module.

Note that this may or may not be a full path and you'll have to test for `"-c"`, the empty string, and otherwise use `os.path.abspath` to get a full path.

Answer (score 0):

try `__file__`.

To get the full path,

```
import os 
print os.path.abspath(__file__)
```

Comment: `__file__` appears to be identical to `sys.argv[0]` for the main script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `__file__`:

> __file__ is the pathname of the file from which the module was loaded, if it was loaded from a file.

This contains an absolute path name, so, in order to get the script file name use:

```
import os
print os.path.basename(__file__)
```

`__file__` works in any case: the file was executed as a script, the file was imported as a module.